# Installing SharpDevelop 4.4 and VS2015 Community side-by-side

Tags: visual-studio, sharpdevelop

I need the C# to VB converter in SharpDevelop 4.4. I already have VS2015 Community installed. I would like to ask if they work nicely together, and whether installing this older version of SharpDevelop *after* installing VS2015 will not cause any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can install SharpDevelop side by side with Visual Studio 2015. There should not be any problems.